# Geometry nodes from previous version are undefined

Tags: geometry-nodes

a while ago I made this geometry node, but formatted the pc and downloaded the latest version of blender 3.0 and it just turns red and doesn't load[image]

Comment: Geometry nodes have changed alot between blender versions recently. If you want it working again the same as before, your best bet would be to use the same version of blender it was created on. If you  would rather keep working with the newest version of blender, you will have to do a little research into how the nodes have changed over the versions, and try to find the "modern" equivalents to use for your node setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Edit > Preferences > Experimental and turn on "Geometry Nodes Legacy".

[image]